# Checking for blank input with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm submitting some comments via $.ajax. However I want to check to make sure that some content is entered in the input box. At the moment I am using this:

```
if ($("#comments").val().length != 0){
```

However this only works if a user leaves in the input blank, if the leave a space or return then it will pass. How can I improve this if?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Remove whitespace before checking for empty:

```
if ($("#comments").val().replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "").length != 0){
```

Comment: would this be any more useful than just using a trim?

Comment: @Chris - no - I just didn't know about jQuery's trim function.

Answer (score 19):

you might go for a `trim`-function ... [google](http://www.google.com/search?q=trim+javascript) give us some nice links.
btw ... jQuery does have a [trim-function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/)

eg.

```
var trimmedValue = jQuery.trim($('#comments').val());
if (trimmedValue.length > 0) {
   // TODO
}
```

Comment: Untested but I would think you could go further and do jQuery.trim($("#comments").val()).length since the trim returns a string anyway. Not that the extra variable is really going to hurt anything.

Comment: as i'm always a friend of introducing extra variables, to have some possibility to debug, i would leave it that way :)

Comment: Can't argue that. I'm just in the habit (good or bad) of avoiding extra variables if I won't be reusing them. I could see a good case of reusing this if you're going to validate the actual content though.

Comment: yeah :) as i'm always validating & validating & ... i would reuse this variable!

Answer (score 2):

In JavaScript

```
//Following all return true
"" == false
" " == false
"  " == false
"   " == false
//Not related to question but interesting
//Following all (also) return true
!" " == false
!"  " == false
!"   " == false
//Except
!"" == false //returns false
```

(Verified with Firebug console and Chromium's Developer Tools console).

Comment: Ok, aldo it's a very weird way to check a statement, I give you that it works: http://jsfiddle.net/cn2YH/2/

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an incredibly late answer, but I am using this...

```
var self = $(this).val(); 
if (!self || self[0] == ' '){
  //////do something
}
```

and it works well! hope someone else can get some use out of it!

Comment: This is not a good idea. What about the case when the user inputs `" valid string"`? You probably wouldn't want to discard that.

Comment: I guess it's possible, but why would anyone want an empty value for their first char?

Comment: Or should I say need an empty value instead of want.

Comment: It's a user input... never trust users to do the right thing!